# What information can I get when "git branch" returns nothing

Tags: git

After a `git clone`, a build was done on a branch.  When I changed directories to the top of the tree and did a *git branch*, nothing was returned.

```
# git branch
* (no branch)
```

Looking at what history I could find, I saw the following:

```
# git clone <repo>
# git checkout -f f4295f4c9e3226d50af3bba48f1a82cdde16ee7a
# get rev-list --no-walk f4295f4c9e3226d50af3bba48f1a82cdde16ee7a
```

If I was not able to find the above information, what **git** command(s) could I have used to track down the **branch name** or even what **hash** the tree was checked out at for the build?

Comment: What do you see with `git branch -a`? That should show you all the remote branch names. Seems like you might be in a `detached HEAD` state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I [ran] *git branch*, nothing was returned.
>
> ```
> # git branch
> * (no branch)
> ```

This isn't *nothing*, exactly.  However, a modern version of Git would print, e.g.:

```
* (HEAD detached at f4295f4c)
```

> [it turns out this resulted from]
>
> ```
> # git checkout -f f4295f4c9e3226d50af3bba48f1a82cdde16ee7a
> ```

Checking out a specific commit by hash ID produces what Git calls a *detached HEAD*.  This is not the only way to get into this state, but it's a common one.  Another common one is to check out a *tag name*, e.g.:

```
$ git checkout v2.21.0
[messages]
Note: switching to 'v2.21.0'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
[snip]

$ git branch
* (HEAD detached at v2.21.0)
```

> If I was not able to find the above information, what **git** command(s) could I have used to track down the **branch name** ...

There may well be *no* branch name.  That's the case when using a raw hash ID and when using a tag name, as shown above.  In Git, commits are *independent of branch names*; no commit is required to be on *any* branch, and any commit can be on *many* branches simultaneously.  Do not assume that there is one branch name for any given commit.

(Contrast with, e.g., Mercurial, where there is *exactly one* branch name for any given commit.  Once made, a commit is on *that branch* forever, or until it is stripped, whichever occurs first.  Branches in Mercurial are solid.  In Git, the *commits* are forever—a commit is solid—but its containing branch names *change* over time.  Branches are fluid, not solid.)

> ... or even what **hash** the tree was checked out at for the build?

A modern Git shows an abbreviated hash ID in the `git branch` output, as shown above.  In all versions of Git, you can always obtain the current hash ID of the current commit using `git rev-parse HEAD`:

```
$ git checkout master
[messages snipped]
$ git rev-parse HEAD
c7a62075917b3340f908093f63f1161c44ed1475
```

If there is a current branch, you can find it using `git symbolic-ref`:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
```

When HEAD is detached, as when checking out a specific commit by hash ID or tag name, the `symbolic-ref` command *fails*, indicating that you're not on a branch at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have no branch locally, which is due to the fact that a build occurred as you have mentioned in your question.

```
git branch -r
```

shows what branches are on the remote repository. You can also run

```
git fetch
```

to fetch the branches.